# How to make a index.html file for your website

Tags: 7

Would just like to ask a question in context of how to create a index.html file I will provide some info below in a brief paragraph so it's straight forward and easy to understand.

I have a localhost site which was just finished and a domain and everything but when I used filezilla to upload and after uploaded when I visited my site all I saw was " Index of" and then the name beside a bullet and when clicked just denies me access. I am now aware I need a index.html file I just need a hand from someone on here to point me in the right direction of what to actually put inside , where to put and if there are any other things I should be aware about. Thanks for your time I appreciate it

Comment: a standard install of Drupal creates an index.php file. If it functions on local, but not on production, it either didn't copy correctly or your server is not set up correctly - either way, the question appears off-topic here

Comment: make sure you have uploaded the hidden .htaccess file also make sure you have sufficient permission to read the PHP files.

you can check this article on how to setup you drupal site permissions https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: hey thanks for the replies appreciate it.. what happened was an error on my part. What I did when I was using filezilla & transferring my files over is I was dragging the whole file over like how it's organized in the local host so MAMP>HTDOCS>MYSITE>FILES  and dragging over (MYSITE) in this example which caused the ugly "index of" problem .. solution to transfer the files living inside MYSITE. Now just sorting out login difficulties after migration